# Increase limit of a VARCHAR in grails

Tags: string, grails

In grails i have declared a variable in the Model called. `String dnaSequence`

I am trying to to save a huge long `string` into it and i get the following error message saying its too big.

How can i increase the limit to `900,000` or more ?

How can i achieve this?

Note: The solution given should be something that i can achieve with `Grails`.

My Domain class

```
class Animal {


    String dnaSequence

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max size of a VARCHAR is set in the database, Grails doesn't have any say in the matter. What you can do is tell Grails what you need, and it will generate DDL that uses a clob instead of a string.

Change the mapping for the column to use `type: "text"`, while adding the maxSize you want in your constraints. Grails will figure out from this that it should set the column data type to clob.

(Generally a clob field will hold up to 4GB, though some databases allow changing that.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But It seems like you can't set the default value for columns with this data type. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [type mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html) in GORM. Specifically, you could add this to change the type of the `dnaSequence` field:

```
static mapping = {
    dnaSequence type: "text"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use database mapping in your domain class

```
class Book {
    String name
    Status status

    static mapping = {
        delegate.name column: "name", sqlType: "text", length: 2000
    }
}
```

For more details
https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html